# Transition between ViewControllers is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have a button in a viewcontroller which I linked with another ViewController.

On the implementation of the first viewController I created this method:

```
- (IBAction)SignUpPressed:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signup" sender:self];
}
```

But when I test it on the simulator, I press the button and the app crashes

```
argc    int 1   1
argv    char ** 0x7fff5fbfece8  0x00007fff5fbfece8


libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Returning this errors.
What can I do to fix this?

APPENDIX:

Code around the error (all code is above the error point)

```
    #import "LoginViewController.h"
    #import "ADVTheme.h"

    @interface LoginViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation LoginViewController



    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        id <ADVTheme> theme = [ADVThemeManager sharedTheme];

        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[theme viewBackground]]];



        [self.loginButton setBackgroundImage:[theme colorButtonBackgroundForState:normal] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;

         [self.loginButton setBackgroundImage:[theme colorButtonBackgroundForState:UIControlStateHighlighted] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        self.title = @"Login";
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

        // Return the number of sections.
        return 0;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 0;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell;
    }

All exception Traceback


014-02-01 11:55:05.904 theBeeGame[15793:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<LoginViewController: 0x10982c3b0>) has no segue with identifier 'signup''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f90795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101cf3991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   UIKit                               0x0000000100a43e05 -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
    3   theBeeGame                          0x0000000100005cf1 -[LoginViewController SignUpPressed:] + 97
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000100957096 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000100957044 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100a2b450 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100a2a9c0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010098bc15 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010098c633 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 988
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000100965fa2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000100953d7f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9549
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f1fec1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f1f792 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f3b61f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101f3af33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010293c3a0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000100956043 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    18  theBeeGame                          0x0000000100002ed3 main + 115
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001033295fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please Check and ensure that your `IBAction` or `IBOutlet` in your storyboard are correctly hooked up.

Comment: Show the full exception message and stack trace. Is the segue identifier valid?

Comment: I added on tab Identity, RestorationID as "signup". I updated my question with full exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set your segue identifier "signup" on stoarybord controller.

Comment: I added on tab Identity, RestorationID as "signup", but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

the convention on iOS is to have method starting with lowerCase and camelCase. Make sure that your control is hooked up to the correct IBaction (case-sensitive!). Also make sure your segue identifier matches exactly (case-sensitive).

Lastly, show full exception, stack trace and the code around the location where the exception occurs (for this, set an exception breakpoint).

Comment: I added to LoginButton on tab Identity, RestorationID as "signup", but didn't work